# How to design a layout with textview and Image where Image always should align right of textview regardless of length of textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to design a layout where my textview should be left and image on the right,if my text length increases and goes to second line then my image should be second line right.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dhhad asuhdasdh saxax xsaxsx sdjsad sbadsa dcnc" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: sample image ]![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? did you check RelativeLayout? no? [what are you waiting for? christmas?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbvSA6QHG1E)

Comment: yes I tried with relative,linear layout

Comment: oh ... so you tried and you didn't get what you want? it means that it is impossible! (not that i don't belive you, but you didn't provide any layout in your question)

Comment: why you voted negative@Selvin

Comment: post image of what you wana achive and post your layout xml not image of it(maybe someone could fix it) ... but as i sai the easy way is RelativeLayout ImageView anchored to parent right centered vertically then text box parent left and to the left of image view ...

Comment: Try to make a RelativeLayout with the image and the text. Then, you define the property toLeftof on the text.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is just a custom adapter for your TextView?

Comment: @Selvin Posted my layout

Comment: as i said imageview should be first in layout it should be align parent left next textview align parent left and to the left of imageview

Comment: @Selvin can you post the layout

Comment: you can use linear layout and use weight property.

Comment: sure http://selvin.pl/da_layout.png

Comment: I used that too,in that case the imageview is fixed at the right even when the text length is short@PiYusHGuPtA

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution...

Set the image to **layout_alignParentRight="true"** and then the textview **layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"** and this should solve your issue.

Edit: You will also need to add **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"** on the textView to make sure it stays left aligned when the text is shorter.

Obviously I have just mocked it up using an empty imageview with a background colour to test, you will need to make this fit into your example.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Some text here to see what happens. does it wrap?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you forgot align parent left in text view ... try short text and see what happend ...

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I dont want to make the imageview width and height fixed as I am using drawable and also the image fixed at the right even when the length of text is short and when the text length increased imageview not coming to second line,I want the image to be align at the end of textview regardless of the length.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="dhhad asuhdasdh saxax xsaxsx sdjsad sbadsa dcnc" />
```

Comment: Main thing is when text length increases and comes to second line then image also come to second line after text and when text is short one line then image should be beside that text